# Lambda de-serializer

Tags: amazon-web-services, deserialization, aws-lambda

I have a Pojo class which is not primitive, because it has references of other POJOs as well.

AWS-Lambda is not able to de-serialize into my POJO. It seems that lambda honors only primitive POJOs.

Eg:

```
class BasePojo {
   String bac;
}

class Composite {
   BasePojo b;
}
```

We are passing Composite Pojo in the lambda handler.

I am stuck for long in this.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Can you please share your Lambda handler function?

Comment: +1 @VijayanathViswanathan. Have you taken Composite/BasePojo as input to your lambda function? It would be more clear if you can add code for lambda function